# Cassandra cqlengine increase logging verbosity

Tags: python, logging, cassandra, cql, cqlengine

I am new to cassandra python client. I am currently debugging an issue that I am having with my local cassandra client. For the same, I want to increase the logging verbosity on the cassandra cqlengine client. I want to see detailed logs on what the client is doing as its making database calls. I couldn't find anyway to do it using the client api's that are defined in the documentation.

I am using cassandra cqlengine version `3.3.0` with python `2.6`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cqlengine` uses standard Python logging. You can enable by configuring logging for the entire driver package, or select modules.

[This log statement](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/3.8.0/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py#L339) will show you statements going out of `cqlengine` (but not the actual bound attribute values. To setup basic console logging:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('cassandra.cqlengine.connection')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```